# Selenium PhantomJS webdriver unable to click a WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I'm setting up a test environment. In my JUnit test class I'm first creating a salesforce record:
driver.findElement(By.id("acc2")).sendKeys("New Salesforce Record");
driver.findElement(By.name("save")).click();

so far so good.

After saving this record I now want clean up with a deletion of the same record. The WebElement is accessed with:
driver.findElement(By.name("delete")).click();

JUnit test goes through and the button delete is found and clicked on. However the record is still there and not removed properly. So the WebElement is not responding to me clicking it.

Does anyone know how this can be resolved? I'm looking at the Selenium WebElement Interface and it says that "preconditions for an element to be clicked. The element must be visible and it must have a height and width greater then 0" which I've made sure is the case.

So what could be the problem and how can I make the button respond to be clicking it?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in Selenium? Maybe the code that is being tested is not working properly - and not deleting the record?

Comment: Afraid that I'm not sure of anything Dylan but the source code from the page indicates that I'm accessing the correct component and the JUnit test goes through. So the Element is found and clicked otherwise there would be an exception?

I was orginally using Selenium IDE and Firefox webdriver which deleted the record. As I clicked the component with the Firefox webdriver a  JavaScript alert was triggered and I handled it in my test.However no alert is raised when using Phantom webdriver even though I compare the two web sources and see that also Phantom has JavaScript alert embedded.

Comment: Also I tried setting desired capabilities of the webdriver so JavaScript is enabled:  
((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true); 
WebDriver  driver = new  PhantomJSDriver(caps);

But still no alerts. Don't know if that even is the missing part for me to successfully click the delete button.